# multiple htaccess redirects with http to https but except page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i  use mod_rewrite to allow "friendly URLS" to replace search parameters, which works fine.
However i need to now redirect all traffic to https:// but allow only some pages to remain on http://
(i need to do this so my referrals are collected by the sites i send traffic to)

Over the years i have added to the .htaccess file, most  works OK but i dont fully understand it, so it may be getting messy too :-(

i have the below (i have cut out anything i dont think is relevant)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9'/-]+)-([0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
# NOTE: this allows for profile.php?id=123 to be replaced with /profile/name-123

# redirects any http:// traffic to https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

The above works OK, but redirect ALL pages to https

I have tried adding /changing the https redirect part to the below to allow urlout.php not to be redirected, but this just loops and i get a browser warning that the page has too many redirects :-(

```
# redirects any http:// traffic to https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/urlout\.php
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

I have tried a few other things too, but they either dont redirect and everything goes to https, or i get a loop error or internal 500 error...

Basically i want all pages to go to https, but not urlout.php

Any advice on any of the code above would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own questions:

i managed to do this, was a silly mistake of me not adding [NC] after the first condition...

However, for others, the below code will redirect ALL to https:// from http:// with the exception of 1 page (urlout.php in my case)

```
# redirects any http:// traffic to https:// with exception of urlout.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/urlout\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I needed to do this, so that sites i send traffic to can see my domain as the "HTTP referrer".

I however found a simpler way to pass the referrer from https to http (although browser specific!) of adding to the HTML head:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

My ref for this was (among others): [moz.com's Meta Referrer Tag Blog Post](https://moz.com/blog/meta-referrer-tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect some spacific pages to https, forexample, To redirect :

- http://www.example.com/page.html

to

- https://www.example.com/page.html

And

- http://www.example.com/page2.html

to
- https://www.example.com/page2.html

You may try the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(page|page2)\.html$ https://www.example.com/$1.html [L,R]
```

If you want to redirect the whole site from http to https, you can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on



 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

**RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off** is important to avoid redirect loop as it skips the rule for https requests.

Comment: I think this anwer doesn't actually accomplish what the OP has asked for, which is to specifically opt specific pages out of the HTTPS redirect, and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the oposite of what i want. i have tried swapping things around from what you said, but this give internal server error (500). i want to redirect the whole site but NOT page.php or page1.php